# Python: How to access a subordinate Column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, finance

i'm Sven and  right before to say i am an absolute beginner with Python. I rode the books "Beginning with Python" and "Python for Data Analysis" to get at least a basic understanding for what i'm doing. My goal with the code below is, that i would like to show the Volume of S&P500 with a rolling Mean of the last 250 days. Means combine a barchart(seaborn) with a line chart(matplotlib.pyplot).

The problem arise in plotting the "S&P500 data by Volume with seaborn as a barchart because i can not access on the subordinate column " Date" . I have an idea but im not quite sure how to start. Has anybody an idea? Thanks a lot.

My approach is anywher between Index, Hierachical and Grouping.

```
           Open   High    Low  Close  Adj Close     Volume
Date                                                        
1993-02-01 438.78 442.52 438.78 442.52     442.52  238570000
1993-02-02 442.52 442.87 440.76 442.55     442.55  271560000
1993-02-03 442.56 447.35 442.56 447.20     447.20  345410000
1993-02-04 447.20 449.86 447.20 449.56     449.56  351140000
1993-02-05 449.56 449.56 446.95 448.93     448.93  324710000

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

yesterday = datetime.now()-timedelta(1)
datetime.strftime(yesterday, "%Y-%m-%d")

SP500 = yf.download('^GSPC', start='1993-02-01', end=yesterday)
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.2f' % x)

SP500f = SP500.head()
SP500f.groupby

#Stats_Vol = SP500["Volume"]
#Date = SP500["Date"]
#print(Stats_Vol)
#print(Stats_Vol.describe())

#sns.barplot(data=SP500, y="Volume")
#print(Stats_Vol.rolling(250).mean().plot())
plt.show()
```

Comment: In your original DataFrame Date is the index. You can make it a column by `data = data.reset_index()`, if that's what you mean

Comment: SP500 = pd.DataFrame(data=yf.download('^GSPC', start='1993-02-01', end=yesterday).reset_index())  seems to work! Thanks a lot @mcsoini :)

Answer (score 1):

Primarily you need to access the *Date* which is the index

- could `reset_index()` to make it a column
- there are two many dates to plot so resampled and then created a new column for display format on x-axis

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

yesterday = datetime.now()-timedelta(1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

SP500 = yf.download('^GSPC', start='1993-02-01', end=yesterday)

# too many days, resample
# do a display format for date (which is the index)
sns.barplot(data=SP500.loc[:,"Volume"]\
            .resample("Y").mean().to_frame()\
            .assign(GDate=lambda dfa: dfa.index.strftime("%Y")), 
            x="GDate", y="Volume", ax=ax)
# rotate the labels
l = ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation = 90)
```

[image]

Comment: i just wanted to comment that reset the index ( Date to Column) causes another problem because i could not group the years because there is no index and because without grouping there are too many data. Hence many thanks for that but because of the data=SP500.loc[:,"Volume"]\
            .resample("Y").mean().to_frame() i think its unable now to include the rolling 250 days Mean right?